# How to make timer not to restart after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've written the following HTML and JS code, but not able to get the actual result. I want the timer not to restart after I refresh the page.

```js
var spd = 1000;
var spdVal = 1;
var cntDown = 5 * 60 * spdVal; 
cntDown += 7;
   setInterval(function () {
   var mn, sc, ms;
   cntDown--;
   if (cntDown < 0) {return false;}
   mn = Math.floor((cntDown / spdVal) / 60);
   mn = (mn < 10 ? '0' + mn : mn);
   sc = Math.floor((cntDown / spdVal) % 60);
   sc = (sc < 10 ? '0' + sc : sc);
   ms = Math.floor(cntDown % spdVal);
   ms = (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms);
   var result = mn + ':' + sc;
     document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = result;
   }, spd);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="stopwatch"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: save the time in localStorage in a `beforeunload` event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the timer is restarting after page refresh is that the countdown time is not being saved anywhere. Each time the page is refreshed, the script starts the countdown from the beginning again.

So if you want your data to remain the same after the refresh, it should be stored in the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` of the browser

```
        var spdVal = 1;

        var cntDown = localStorage.getItem("countdownTime") || 5 * 60 * spdVal + 7;

        setInterval(function () {
            var mn, sc, ms;
            cntDown--;
            if (cntDown < 0) { return false; }
            mn = Math.floor((cntDown / spdVal) / 60);
            mn = (mn < 10 ? '0' + mn : mn);
            sc = Math.floor((cntDown / spdVal) % 60);
            sc = (sc < 10 ? '0' + sc : sc);
            ms = Math.floor(cntDown % spdVal);
            ms = (ms < 10 ? '0' + ms : ms);
            var result = mn + ':' + sc;
            document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = result;

            localStorage.setItem("countdownTime", cntDown.toString());

        }, spd);
```

This is how your js should look like,
See line 2 where we are looking in local store if there is any existing value that we can use or default value.
See line 15 where are setting the time on each update on screen.